# Update Azure DevOps work item parent status if all child elements are closed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webhooks, azure-workflow-automation

I am following this project and instructions https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions

Everything is clear except the part where I need to enter URL when creating webhook in service hooks:

[image]

How to generate that URL?

When I test the link I get this error or 404

[image]

Is there anything that I missed. Should I create something on Azure platform, webhook event or something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy this to something (IIS, Azure App Service, etc)
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions/tree/master/src/AutoStateTransitions

Once deployed, put the URL from your deployed API as the webhook URL.

Comment: I deployed it to IIS. Now when I test the URL of webhook, I get the 500 response. https://website.com/UpdateWorkItem/api/receiver/webhook/workitem/update